# in $\mathbb{R^2}$ , observe that if $A = I \times {\{0}\}$ and $B = {\{0}\} \times I$ (where $I = [0,1]$) then $A + B = I \times I$.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Show that there exists closed sets $A$ and $B$ with $m(A) = m(B) = 0$, but $m(A+B) > 0$. where $A = C$ where  $C$ is the cantor set, and $B = C/2$.

(b) in $\mathbb{R^2}$ , observe that if $A = I \times {\{0}\}$ and $B = {\{0}\} \times I$ (where $I = [0,1]$) then $A + B = I \times I$.

attempt: Suppose  in $\mathbb{R^2}$ , observe that if $A = I \times {\{0}\}$ and $B = {\{0}\} \times I$ (where $I = [0,1]$). Then let $z_1 = (x_1,y_1) \in I$, and  $a \in A $ such that $a = z_1 \times I = (x_1,y_1) \times I$ and $b \in B$ such that $b = {\{0}\} \times I =  {\{0}\} \times (x_2 ,y_2) $.
I don't know how to continue. Can someone please help me? Thank you!

Comment: Hint (a): if $C$ is the Cantor set, what is the sum set $$ C + C := \{ a+ b : a,b \in C \}? $$

Comment: Hint (b): given a point $(a,b) \in I \times I$, can you write it as a sum of an element from $I \times \{ 0 \}$ with an element from $\{0\} \times I$? What does a typical element of $I \times \{0\}$ look like? Of $\{0\} \times I$?

Comment: I thought an element in $I \times {\{0}\}$ was like I had tried from the beginning

Comment: amcerbu, we have $C + C$ is $A + 2 B?$

Comment: It may help to think about the Cantor set as the set of all ternary expansions using only the "digits" 0 and 2.

Comment: I did that for part a) . But I don't know how that would help for part b)

Comment: An element of $I \times \{0\}$ is a point $(a,0) \in \mathbb R^2$. Similarly an element of $\{0\} \times I$ is a point $(0,b) \in \mathbb R^2$. And every $(a,b) \in I \times I$ can be written $(a,0) + (0,b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $(x,y)+S$ is simply to shift $S$ by $x$ in $x$-axis and $y$ in $y$-axis. Thus we can define
$$
(x,y)+S=\bigcup_{(u,v)\in S}(x+u, y+v)
$$ 
Hence
\begin{align}
A+B&=\bigcup_{(x,y)\in A}(x,y)+B
\\
&=\bigcup_{(x,y)\in A}((x,y)+B)
\\
&=\bigcup_{(x,y)\in A}\bigcup_{(u,v)\in B}(x+u,y+v)
\\
&=\bigcup_{(x,y)\in I\times\{0\}}\bigcup_{(u,v)\in \{0\}\times I}(x+u,y+v)
\\
&=\bigcup_{x\in I}\bigcup_{v\in I}(x+0,0+v)
\\
&=\bigcup_{x\in I}\bigcup_{v\in I}(x,v)
\\
&=I\times I
\end{align}